# Convert multiple excel files into PDF files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel-2007, win32com, pdf-conversion

The **win32com** package works fine on a single excel file when converting it into a pdf. But when I run it in a loop to convert multiple excel files, it fails and gives an error message. `(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146777998), None)`

For single File:-

```
from win32com import client

input_file =r"...\input.xlsx"
output_file = r"...\ouput.pdf"
excel  = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
excel.Interactive = False
excel.Visible = False
Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(input_file,None, True)
try:
    Workbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, output_file)
    print("PDF Created successfully!!")
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed, try again")
    print(str(e))
```

For multiple files:-

```
from win32com import client
import os

directory = "...directory path"
path = os.path.join(directory)
for f in os.listdir(directory):
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f) #split file name and extention
    inputFilePath = directory+ "/" + f
    outputFilePath = file_name + '.pdf'
    if file_extension == '.xlsx':
        excel  = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
        excel.Interactive = False
        excel.Visible = False
        Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(inputFilePath , None, True)
        try:
            Workbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, outputFilePath)
            print("processing..")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed, try again")
```

I would appreciate any suggestions you can make. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this solution might be too late for you. I think your problem comes from inputfilepath and outputfilepath variables. I've tweaked your code and is working.

`

```
from win32com import client
import os

directory = r"....directory path...."
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)  # split file name and extension
    input_file_path = os.path.join(directory, file)
    output_file_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name + '.pdf')
    if file_extension == '.xlsx' or file_extension == '.xls':
        excel = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
        excel.Interactive = False
        excel.Visible = False
        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(input_file_path, None, True)
        workbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, output_file_path)
```

`

Comment: Hi @Mulalo Rambau, When I ran my code on an active Windows system, I got multiple PDF files without any error. :)